# How could difficult to control & dangerous creatures be used in combat?

Tags: near-future, genetic-engineering

How could difficult to control & dangerous creatures be used in combat? They are available in large amounts as by by products of creating more effective & useable creatures & they are expendable.

Most of these creatures are in the 6-8ft tall range & humanoid. The ones at the bottom end of strength scale for these things have the ability to get through body armour to the top end ones being able to get through a lightly armoured vehicle, with outliers being able to get through medium armoured vehicles like IFVs. Most have the ability to tank several bullets up to the scale of a 7.62, with smaller bullets sometimes taking over a dozen to knock one down but larger bullets like 7.62 NATO only taking 8-4 to take one down. Larger ones require HMGs to take down.

They are about as smart as a crow but still tend to attack almost anyone outside of their handlers. But they can be kept away from certain areas using pheromone emitters that they don't like to be around. They have little to no self preservation instinct. They often suffer from numerous medical issues due to being products of failure to produce a different genetically modified & more useful creature. They are afraid of of fire.

They don't have much in the way of support as these are failures to produce something more useful. With the resources being better allocated to successfully created creatures that would be more combat effective. There are about 3 handlers for each ~dozen of these creatures. The creatures are trained not to attack their handlers. They are transported in vehicles capable of carrying about ~15 of the creatures + their handlers & can resist HMG fire. They fight in an environment similar to modern day but with small amounts of melee units as well

These groups internally vary massively in combat ability & intelligence but most are around a roughly dog level of intelligence. They are transported in large vehicles capable of carrying ~20-30 of the creatures. 6 handlers are available for every 20-25 of the creatures. These handlers have tasers, conventional firearms & armour capable of resisting 80% of what the creatures can do, they are genetically modified to be stronger than most of the creatures.  Not much can be expended on them as they are the failed results of attempts to make other creatures & the organization that utilises these creatures would get better use out of the resources on successfully modified creatures & soldiers. The enemies they face have a roughly near future level of technology & use modern combat tactics. It would be preferable to have them able to operate alongside conventional forces that also have roughly near future level of technology.