# How could powerful, roughly humanoid but difficult-to-control creatures be used in combat?

Tags: warfare, near-future, genetic-engineering

How could a large amount of powerful roughly humanoid but difficult to control creatures be used? They are available in large amounts as by by products of creating more effective & useable creatures & they are expendable.

Most of these creatures are in the 6-8ft tall range & humanoid. The ones at the bottom end of strength scale for these things have the ability to get through body armour to the top end ones being able to get through a lightly armoured vehicle, with outliers being able to get through medium armoured vehicles like IFVs. Most have the ability to tank several bullets up to the scale of a 7.62, with smaller bullets sometimes taking over a dozen to knock one down but larger bullets like 7.62 NATO only taking 8-4 to take one down. Larger ones require HMGs to take down.

They are about as smart as a crow but still tend to attack almost anyone outside of their handlers. But they can be kept away from certain areas using pheromone emitters that they don't like to be around. They have little to no self preservation instinct. They often suffer from numerous medical issues due to being products of failure to produce a different genetically modified & more useful creature. They are afraid of of fire.

They don't have much in the way of support as these are failures to produce something more useful. With the resources being better allocated to successfully created creatures that would be more combat effective. There are about 3 handlers for each ~dozen of these creatures. The creatures are trained not to attack their handlers. They are transported in vehicles capable of carrying  about ~15 of the creatures + their handlers & can resist HMG fire. They fight in an environment similar to modern day but with small amounts of melee units as well.

(note: this is a clearer re-ask of a previous question)

Comment: VTC:ND (I just VTCd another Q for similar reasons), but VTC:NF, too, as you're asking *at least* 4 questions and you're only allowed to ask one ("other weird creatures" contemplates an infinite number). These creatures would be useless against a tank and godlike against a child - but neither circumstance is rejected by this Q. Please provide for one, specific creature, details about the creature's combat abilities, disposition of ally and enemy forces, circumstances of battle, technology level, etc. We can't make bricks without straw.

Comment: 1) If there's no training or bonding, these creatures will probably turn on their handlers immediately.  You want to airdrop them behind enemy lines to cause disruption instead.  2) What are their instincts (genetically) based on?  If their instincts are animal based, fire (i.e flamethrowers) and explosions / gunfire (animals have to be trained not to be skittish in battle) used by the enemy will panic the creatures beyond any hope of control by the handlers.

Comment: @JBH the problem with providing a specific creature is that i have specific creatures with specific jibs, and these aren't one of them. These are the result of failure to produce one of those more specific creatures. There isn't standardisation because they weren't made intentionally. I can't provide specific enemy because the enemy could range from a well equipped force to a random 3rd world nation that has nothing made after 1980 to massive insects in caves. also i fixed the tags

Comment: Can you see our problem, though? You want us to explain how valuable (or valueless) any number of undefined creatures are to any number of undefined circumstances. SE's basic model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer and the [help/dont-ask] states "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where [(a)] every answer is equally valid, [(b)] there is no actual problem to be solved, and [(c)] you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question." Since I don't think it's possible for you to objectively pick a best answer, I had to VTC.

Comment: I suggest splitting this up into separate questions for each creature and giving us a much more detailed description of each creature including limitations and what they can do, as it sits this is too many vague questions to fit this site.

Comment: "They are somewhat intelligent" - what does it mean, specifically? Are they capable of communication (between themselves) or any kind of group tactics? My first thought when I read the description was cannon fodder - throw them in enemy territory and make them thin out enemy numbers and drain ammunition

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza they're about as smart as a crow

Comment: Rather than asking a new question, you should really go back and edit your [closed old question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/207591/how-could-difficult-to-control-dangerous-creatures-be-used-in-combat) after deleting this one. It will then enter the reopen queue and stand a pretty good chance of receiving the answer that you're looking for - else it's likely that this will just be closed as a duplicate anyhow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could difficult to control & dangerous creatures be used in combat?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/207591/how-could-difficult-to-control-dangerous-creatures-be-used-in-combat)

Comment: @ARogueAnt. that was a question i made that got closed before i got a good answer for not being specific enough, so i made a new question that's more well defined

Comment: Which is not what you're meant to do, as per my previous comment, please edit the old one.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. i edited the old question

Comment: Much appreciated. This version has been flagged for a moderator to merge with the other one, so you don't lose the answers here.

Comment: Why have you edited this to make it an exact copy of the other question you have posted today?

Comment: @L.Dutch someone on the other one got annoyed & told me to edit this one rather than re-ask the question (also there are a few minor differences)

Comment: The older, closed question has now been merged into this one.

Comment: The second and third paragraphs of the question contain the parameters of every scenario these creatures could be expected to achieve some degree of success in, so any conceivable best answer is going to be a variation within that set. Does Situation X meet the parameters? If yes, deployment is a use case.

Answer (score 1):

**Shock Troopers.**

You can use them to instil dread and demoralize, as well as not caring if they die in droves after a Zerg Rush.

Your more valuable elements go after them, when the enemy has been broken.

Answer (score 1):

**Terror bombing.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_bombing

> Howard Cowan, an Associated Press war correspondent, filed a story
> about the Dresden raid. The military press censor at SHAEF made a
> mistake and allowed the Cowan cable to go out starting with "Allied
> air bosses have made the long awaited decision to adopt deliberate
> terror bombing of great German population centers as a ruthless
> expedient to hasten Hitler's doom."

These monsters are of little use on a battlefield.  In a city, however, they will stumble around and cause a lot of terrifying damage.  They will be used to damage civilian morale and terrorize the populace.  It is bad enough to have bombs fall on you, but they are just stupid bombs.  If monsters dropped from planes are stumbling through your city, hiding in dark places, and bashing their way into shelters that is even more terrifying.

Your monsters are dropped into or near enemy cities in a maneuver similar to terror bombing.  Near cities might be good because the planes will attract less attention and the monsters will make their way through the night for the final mile or two, attracted by the city.

Answer (score 1):

**Sabotage/supply chain attacks**

Your creatures are tough (but not tough enough to survive on a mechanized battlefield with IFVs, tanks, and rocket launchers) and can chew through most industrial-grade materials with relative ease. With their low intelligence and (what I assume to be) no better than human-grade mobility, they're better kept away from enemies that can offer organized resistance.

So where do you find a bunch of hardened targets that don't shoot back? Well, a factory perhaps, or a motor pool, or a rail yard. These creatures are basically shaped charges that carry and plant themselves. (Targeting specific parts of a vehicle or machine shouldn't be beyond a bird-like intelligence, or their handlers can mark targets by hand.) The handlers scout the facility during the day and bring in the creatures at night to wreak havoc, then leave before anything turns up capable of fighting back. A lone watchman or plant worker won't likely be able to stop them, and passive security (fences, doors) would have to be pretty formidable to hold back a creature that can rip through trucks.

Answer (score 0):

So you describe them as "basically dogs," "stronger humans," and "giant humans."

In our world, dogs do not have a place in combat situations where both sides are lethally armed.  They are used for their nose and for their ability to chase down suspects.

Unarmed humans, even if they are stronger than normal, also have no place in a gunfight.

Unarmed giants could be taken down as easily as unarmed humans, if the gun is designed for it.  Perhaps more easily, because giants would be less agile and present a larger target.

For any of them to be useful in combat you'll need to cover them in bullet-resistant armor.  However, the enemy can respond by using heavier guns.  Perhaps you can say that the monsters are all *much* stronger for their size than humans, which would allow them to carry around much thicker and more bulletproof armor, like tanks.

Answer (score 0):

Every action / decision has an opportunity cost. Training handlers, deploying handlers, making equipment, logistics etc all have a cost namely the foregone uses / actions / deployments of other things / people.

As these creatures are not sophonts (“crow-level” intelligence”) and are by-products of something else, I’d suggest the optimal use for them is as food - whether that’s for humans, livestock or ground-up as plant fertiliser. Noting that they have been “trained“ but only “ not to attack the handler” - I’d still argue that you’re best move is to sacrifice that training and still use them as fodder for something else. Given the scenario posted, They’re next to useless otherwise.

If you really must deploy them in combat. Get them behind enemy lines somehow and unleash them as a horde on the enemy. The enemy will have to redirect resources to their own territory to hunt and destroy them. Plus you have the added bonus of terror tactics. Beware this would likely carry severe diplomatic consequences.

But, look, it probably wouldn’t work anyway because of the huge logistics task of moving them in large numbers so as to hassle the enemy (it’s that opportunity cost at work again; you’d be better off using the time, effort and resources to do something else). Plus these creatures have limited intelligence so it wouldn’t be that hard or costly for the enemy to track them down and eliminate them.

Plant food. It’s the best use for them.

Comment: hi user87105, try to answer the question, that is keep to the proposed scenario. You could keep the first and third sentence in, and remove the rest. These creatures *have* been trained. It would not be very cost-effective to eat them, or use them as plant fertilizers, after that training. Also, this is not about Roman times, the question has no "settings". This is about using these creatures in *modern* warfare.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding 87105, please take our [tour] and read-up in the [help] about how we work. Enjoy the site. @Goodies is quite correct, we prefer focused questions and answers, we're neat-n-tidy that way.